# django decorator check if user is logged in otherwise redirect

Tags: django, redirect, authentication

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login_user'))
```

since i was doing the above, in most of my views I figured there should be something better then putting that piece in all my views.

now i found something about decoraters that seems to do a bit what i want:

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

@require_http_methods(["GET", "POST"])
def my_view(request):
```

Now i wondered is this indeed done with decorators and if so how can i translate that to check if a user is logged in and redirect otherwise?

Comment: Please read [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator)

Answer (score 6):

You can use built-in decorator:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def edit_user_profile(request):
    //some code
```

[django login_required decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator)

Comment: Is there an overview about all the build-in decorators?   i only found this page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/decorators/#module-django.views.decorators.http

Comment: When i set my login url to my "homepage"  LOGIN_URL = ' '  I get an error when i actualy try to acces a page that uses the @login_required  error: "Reverse for '^$' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found."   How do i fix this?

Comment: In LOGIN_URL you should pass url (or function name or named url pattern) which point to your login page.